# Swashbuckle aspnet core 2.0 Swaggerconfig.cs not created

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to install `Swashbuckle` to my web api in `aspnet core 2.0`. Reading all over google about how to set it up it's written about the `SwaggerConfig.cs` under the **App_Start-folder**.

> But when I install it never gets created?? Where is it?

All I can do is setting up the basics in `Start.cs`, and it's just some basics? Where is the `SwaggerConfig.cs` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of swashbuckle:

- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

There is no SwaggerConfig file on the AspNetCore version.

Your configuration goes on the Startup.cs:
[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#getting-started](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)

Comment: Ah okey. So with the aspnetcore-version there's a very limited set of configurations I guess, because I could find out how to add a custom api-token-auth, it's done in the swaggerconfig-file. Thank you!

Comment: There is plenty of configuration options, take a look at this section in the readme file: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#configuration--customization